# How to retrieve a collection out of an SOAP message

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I'm using a webservice for render company information based on a special company number.
But i can not get data out of the response SOAP message.
You can see an example of the response soap message. (I left out some company information the tags).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<businessGetDossierV3Response xmlns="http://www.webservices.nl/soap/">
<out>
<paging>
<curpage>1</curpage>
<perpage>10</perpage>
<numpages>1</numpages>
<numresults>1</numresults>
<maxresults>100</maxresults>
</paging>
<results>
<item>
<DossierNo></DossierNo>
<SubDossierNo></SubDossierNo>
<ChamberNo></ChamberNo>
<Legalformcode></Legalformcode>
<LegalformcodeText></LegalformcodeText>
<Tradename45></Tradename45>
<EstablishmentPostcode></EstablishmentPostcode>
<EstablishmentCity></EstablishmentCity>
<EstablishmentStreetname></EstablishmentStreetname>
<EstablishmentHouseNo></EstablishmentHouseNo>
<CorrespondencePostcode></CorrespondencePostcode>
<CorrespondenceCity></CorrespondenceCity>
<CorrespondenceStreetname></CorrespondenceStreetname>
<CorrespondenceHouseNo></CorrespondenceHouseNo>
</item>
</results>
</out>
</businessGetDossierV3Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

! this is the result i see on the demo client !
But this is my code in C#

```
        nl.webservices.ws1.BusinessDossierV3PagedResult result = null;
        result = myserviceBusiness.businessGetDossierV3(KVKnr, "0000", 1);
```

I want to do something like this (but with the results instead of paging part)

```
int page = result.paging.numpages;
```

Then I should be like this I suppose

```
string city = result.results.item.CorrespondenceCity;
```

But this is giving a fault message

So in Visual studio 2010, i can only retrieve the data in the paging part of the xml and put it into a textbox, but not from results part. Is this because the result part is some kind of Collection?

So yes, how can i put the data from the tags EstablishmentPostcode and EstablishmentCity in a textbox on my default page?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding your SOAP service as a web reference to the project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tydxdyw9.aspx

If you don't want to do this and would rather work on the XML directly you could use xpath to get access to all the item elements in your results element. 
http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009031001&page=1

One thing to be careful of when using xpath is that you use the correct xml namespace for the node you're trying to select.

Ben

Comment: Hi Ben , the reference with SOAP is already made. I use the same web reference as for the postcode webservice (which works perfectly), The postcode and this (businessGetDossierV3) webservice are from the same provider (webservices.nl). So I make an instance of this service, and then call the method which does the work and put the result of that method into a object. But now I dont know how to put the result into a string object (because the result object is a special type and could not be typecasted to a string).

Comment: You can't cast it to a string, you can call the ToString() method on it but that probably won't give you the result you expect. You need to iterate the collection and build a string as you go. Google "foreach" and StringBuilder.

Comment: if i iterate or not, i still can not call the value in for example the CorrespondenceStreetname tag

Comment: What is the Type of the result.results property? have you tried string city = result.results[0].CorrespondenceCity;

Comment: you are a hero Ben :) now i can load those properties

Comment: You're welcome, just beware that if there is more than one result that this will ignore all but the first result.